# How to get more then 20 documents in a GET query using Firestore REST API

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

according to firestore docs: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas
"Maximum function call depth" is 20, therefore i am unable to get more documents then 20.
how to change this limitation.(i have already linked my project to billing account).
thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Add this parameter at the end of your request URL.

"&pageSize="

```
for example:
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/<prjct id>/databases/(default)/documents/<doc path>?key=<apikey>&pageSize=100
```

Answer (score 1):

The number 20 is **not** the maximum number of documents you can request. That would be a really unreasonable limit. There is actually no documented limit on the number of documents that can be retrieved, although there likely is a physical limit which mostly will depend on the memory and bandwidth of your app.

It's the maximum depth of [functions calls in the security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#custom_functions) for Cloud Firestore.

Comment: Hi Frank, FYI, if you use the `list` method of the **Firestore REST API** (https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/list) and do not specify a `pageSize` value, you receive only 20 documents. It's a bit surprising, especially since it does not seem to be documented as being a default value.

Comment: Interesting Renaud. I haven't used the REST API enough to encounter that limit. If you think that's what OP was hitting (despite the red herring to irrelevant docs), then Soorya's answer sounds like the way to work around that.

Comment: Indeed, I think it's what the OP encountered (based on the question title) and Soorya's answer is the solution. I just wanted to share this point with you (as I've encountered this problem today and found this SO Q&A) and to take the liberty to indicate that the documentation could maybe mention this default value :-)

Comment: Yeah, it definitely should. Feel like filing a bug, or clicking the "documentation feedback" link in the relevant page?

Answer (score -1):

[My solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxT4i.png)

I managed to temporarily solve the problem by adding a parameter, as shown in the attached image.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).